# ¿Cómo enviar el contenido de un type search en html por post?

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql, ajax

Muy buenas a todos, quiero hacer una búsqueda a través del search, que luego la palabra que envíe se la pasaré a la query dentro de la base de datos, la cosa es que he intentado, y el contenido de ese campo no lo envía por post, a la hora de ejecutar la query para buscar los "productos" y mostrarlos en otra página simplemente me da error de index donde "search" (El nombre de el campo) no existe en la consulta, espero haberme expresado bien, gracias de antemano.

**Input del campo search**

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="<?php echo 
      controlador::$rutaAPP?
      >index.php?action=buscarProducto" method="post" id="formbusqueda" >
       <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="¿Estás 
      buscando algo?" id="search" name="search" value="form">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" 
      type="submit">Buscar</button>
     </form>
```

**Script que envía lo que lleva el campo search**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formbusqueda").submit(function(){
      $.ajax({
        dataType:"json",
        url:"<?php echo controlador::$rutaAPP?>index.php?action=buscarProducto", 
        type:"POST",
        data:$("#formbusqueda").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
          if (data.success) {
            var x = document.getElementById("search").placeholder
          } 
        },
        error: function(response) {

        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Consulta sql donde se pasa el parámetro**

```
<?php  
$mvcDatos=new GetDatos();
    $resultado=$mvcDatos->consultaGen("select productos.titulo,productos.descripcion,productos.precio,productos.stock,productos.foto from productos inner join categorias on productos.id_cate=categorias.id_cate where productos.titulo like '".$_POST["search"]."%'");
        if (count($resultado)==0) {
                $info=array('success'=>false,'data'=>$resultado);

            }else{
                $info=array('success'=>true,'data'=>$resultado);
            }
echo json_encode($info);    
?>
```

**Script que recibe la consulta con el campo search introducido previamente**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        blockDiv("body",1);
        $.ajax({
          dataType: "json",
          url:"<?php echo controlador::$rutaAPP?>index.php?action=busqueda",
          data:{search:$("search").val()},
          type:'GET',
          success: function(data,x) {
            if (data.success==true) {
              blockDiv("body",2)
              var html="<div class='row mt-5'>";
              data.data.forEach(function(item,index){
                html+="<div class='card mx-2' style='width: 18rem;'><img class='card-img-top' src='"+item.foto+"' alt='Card image cap'><div class='card-body'><h5 class='card-title'>"+item.titulo+"</h5><p class='card-text'>"+item.descripcion+"</p></div><ul class='list-group list-group-flush'><li class='list-group-item'><strong>Precio: </strong>$"+item.precio+"<li class='list-group-item'><strong>Stock: </strong>"+item.stock+"</ul><div class='card-body'><a href='<?php echo controlador::$rutaAPP?>index.php?action=hacerpedido' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' role='button' aria-pressed='false'>Hacer pedido</a></div></div>";
              });
              html+="</div>";
              $("#contenedor").html(html);
            }else{
              blockDiv("body",2)
              var html="<div class='row mt-5'>";
              html+="<h3 class='mx-5'>Lo sentimos... No hay productos con ese criterio de búsqueda.</h3>";
              html+="</div>";
              $("#contenedor").html(html);
            } 
          },
          error: function(s,x,y) {
              blockDiv("body",2);
              console.log(x);
          }
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Por favor sube el código para revisarlo

Comment: Hola, pier67. Aunque estás mezclando Ajax con Php, te sugiero hacer algo como un `print_r($_POST);` en tu script php que ejecuta la consulta, de modo de saber qué está recibiendo dicho script por `POST`.

Comment: Estuve probando, y no tengo idea de por qué el ajax no me envía lo quee el campo search lleva, ya que al utilizarlo dentro de la consulta dice que no existe, esto lo comprobé ya que le envíe un parámetro $_SESSION y me lo agarró a la perfección, alguna idea de por qué no me envía lo que el campo tiene mediante el ajax? Es raro, porque en otros forms que tengo me envía todo a la perfección, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien que hagas una búsqueda con dos scripts diferentes, no le veo ninguna utilidad al "Script que envía lo que lleva el campo search" pero bueno. El error que veo a simple vista es que el selector de `$("search").val()`, del último `<script>` no es válido, supongo que querías poner `#search` o `[name=search]`.

Por cierto, si envías el formulario con ajax no es necesario que `<form>` tenga los atributos `action=""` y `method=""`.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias, muy amable por responder, de hecho eso mismo pensaba que el script que lleva el valor de search está por gusto, entonces, quito el action y method del form, pero cómo envío el valor del campo hacia la consulta sql, para que luego el script que recibe la consulta cree los productos en base a lo buscado?

Comment: El error creo que es lo que te he dicho sobre el selector. En la línea 7 del **Script que recibe la consulta con el campo search introducido previamente** pone: `data:{search:$("search").val()},` y como te dije, `$("search")` no es un selector válido. Tienes que poner `$("#search")` para que puedas obtener el valor con `.val()`.

Answer (score -1):

Intenta con `like '%".$_REQUEST["search"]."%'` en tu consulta

PHP `$_REQUEST` sirve para obtener datos despues de que se haga un **submit** en un formulario HTML

Comment: siempre que respondas una pregunta debes añadir una explicación, pues solo poner código se considera de baja calidad; ten siempre presente que las respuestas no solo van para quien pregunto sino para todos lo usuarios presnetes y futuros que la consulten y les debe ser clara

Comment: Bueno gracias por la sugerencia

Comment: Muchas gracias, intentaré eso.